# Get all ListView items?

Tags: android

I want to get all the items in a list view that way when each one is clicked they will open the second activity?
Here I can get a specific list view item and use an if statement to say if this is clicked open/launch the second activity but I want to be able to say if any list view item is clicked open/launch the second activity how do I do that I know it sounds simple??

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
        {




                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

when I remove the if statement it keeps crashing logcat states:"RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list" am using :android:id="@android:id/list" my activity also extends ListActivity? I dont't get it

Comment: Well, try to comment the if statement, like this
// if (listView.getAdapter().getItem(itemPosition).equals("Truck"))

Comment: What you want is that every click, no matter which, oppens the same second activity?

Comment: whenever a crash is related, please include logcat

Comment: i've posted the logcat error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question:

> but I want to be able to say if any list view item is clicked open/launch the second activity how do I do that I know it sounds simple??

Just remove the if block like this:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And your second activity will be opened on any item click.

Hope this helps...